# I want my fantasy world to be as without magic as possible. Tips?

Tags: magic, worldbuilding-process

I want to make a high fantasy fiction world, but I don't like a whole lot of magic and I am falling into a trap that I need it. I don't want no magic, but just enough that it feels like another world. I also don't want it to be a science fiction and there still should be a good amount of magic. I like The Lord of The Rings and want that style of a world. I have no idea how to avoid this. Can I have some information about how to avoid too much magic but still have a bit of realistic magic?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is which your perceptions of how much magic would be "enough that it feels like another world" and "as without magic as possible".

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific problems you are having while developing your world. If you could ask a new question identifying a feature of your world you wish to make more believable or less magical, the community would be happy to help. Asking for "tips" without context is far too broad a topic for the StackExchange format and is likely to be closed as such. Feel free to take the [tour] to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: don't caste spells..?

Comment: What are the circumstances that make you feel like you need it?  Maybe  give some examples of those "traps" you feel like can only be solved with magic infusion.  People might have other ideas on how to sidestep or deal with these traps.

Comment: You want your fantasy world to be as *what* as possible? It would be helpful for you to [edit] your question title to clarify what you mean.

Comment: My suggestion to to make the world magical but make the characters not magical. Thus your story would deal with little magic but the world can have interesting and fantastical things.

Comment: Please describe what your "high fantasy fiction world" should look like. Would [Pandora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora_%E2%80%93_The_World_of_Avatar) be suitable?

Comment: You can make the magic only mimic what you know is currently high tech. levitation (helicopter) and flying, projecting a small mass at supersonic speed (a bullet), divining the landscape (satellite and google maps), long distance vision (binoculars, telescopes), micro vision (microscopes), healing (modern medicine), heavy lifting or digging (modern construction equipment, forklifts), explosions (dynamite, nitro), lightning (electricity, taser), instant learning (Internet). Give it the same limitations as the tech it copies. It won't get out of hand any more than our real life.

Comment: What do you mean by realistic magic? Realistic magic is just technology.

Answer (score 2):

Be imaginative. Make your world less like this world, then it will feel like another world. Create unique problems - what about floating land masses, or fish that come ashore and raid the garbage? Perhaps there is a readily exploitable labour force of goblins, but they will only work at night?

Create magic, which is not really magic, but only poorly understood science. If your characters think it is magic, then it will be magic for them, but you will know it's limitations and will not be encouraged to go beyond them. Your magicians could just be bad scientists.

Be imaginative. Don't create a world that needs magic, or you will need magic.  Magic is a bit of a cheat because it makes it too easy to solve problems (and also less interesting when you do).

Then, if you still want magic, add just a drop.